# Django user get_all_permissions() is empty while user_permissions is set

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-permissions

I added some permissions to a user via the admin interface.

From some reason all the perm functions fail, e.g

```
>>> user.get_all_permissions()
set([])
```

But accessing the table directly, works:

```
>>> user.user_permissions.all()
(list of permissions as expected)
```

What can cause the "get_all_permissions" (and all the perm functions like has_perm()) to fail ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the authentication backends in your settings.py?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

had the same problem.  I am guessing that at some point you have used a self-crafted AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND?  Most examples on the net of this (INCLUDING THE DJANGO 1.0 DOCUMENTATION!) don't mention that the Backends are responsible for permissions handling as well.

However, no biggie: In whatever backend file your code resides, include this import:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
```

Then make sure the Backend you wrote *extends* ModelBackend, e.g.:

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
```

Should be fine.

Comment: Yep, I found it out later.

I modified the backend to support case-insensitive usernames and broke the permissions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because of [permission caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching). I get the user,
added permission to `user.user_permissions` but `user.get_all_permissions` was empty `set()` and `user.has_perm` was `False`. This problem is **only with shell** not admin.

```
user = User.objects.get(username="User")

permission = Permission.objects.get(
    codename="organizations.add_organization",
)
user.user_permissions.add(permission)

user.get_all_permissions()  # set()
user.has_perm('organizations.add_organization')  # False
```

I have to add additional line before checking permissions:

```
user.user_permissions.add(permission)

user = User.objects.get(username="User") # new

user.get_all_permissions()
```