# Django: user.has_perm always returns false

Tags: python, django, authorization

I have a custom user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class TaborUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail', unique=True)
```

Its backend:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q


UserModel = get_user_model()


class EmailBackend(BaseBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        user = UserModel.objects.filter(pk=user_id)
        breakpoint()
        if user:
            return user[0]
        else:
            return None

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = UserModel.objects.filter(email=username)
        if not user:
            user = UserModel.objects.filter(username=username)

        # Both username and e-mail are unique. As long as we don't have
        # a very rogue admin, we should be alright.
        if user:
            user = user[0]
        else:
            return None

        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

The model does not seem to pass this check:

```
class AdminView(PermissionRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = UploadFileForm

    template_name = "admin.html"
    login_url = "/login/"

    permission_required = ("taborapp.view_photomodel",
                           "taborapp.add_photomodel",
                           "taborapp.delete_photomodel", 
                        )
```

When user is added as follows:

```
from taborapp.models import TaborUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

user = TaborUser.objects.create_user("test")

user.email = "test@example.me"
user.set_password("LOLaPublicPassword123")

permissions = []
photo_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="taborapp", model="photomodel")

for codename in "view_photomodel", "add_photomodel", "delete_photomodel":
    perm = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=photo_type, codename=codename)
    permissions.append(perm[0])

user.user_permissions.add(*permissions)

user.save()
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I went over docs and similar issues on stack overflow a few times and I just cannot figure out the issue.

I am too brief for the auto-detection system to believe me that I have described my problem enough. I hope this sentence will satisfy it.

Answer (score 1):

Drop into the Django shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Next,

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    u = User.objects.get(email="test@example.me")
    u.get_user_permissions()
```

Hopefully you'll see what you're looking for in the data returned.  That'll give you a good idea of where to look next.

Comment: >>> u.get_user_permissions()
returns an empty: set()

But:
>>> u.user_permissions.all()
Returns a all of the permissions I'm trying to get: <QuerySet [<Permission: taborapp | photo model | Can add photo model... Can view photo model>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @RiverRook, getting the list of permissions was very helpful as I managed to find the correct thread about this.

[Django user get_all_permissions() is empty while user_permissions is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081061/django-user-get-all-permissions-is-empty-while-user-permissions-is-set)